# Is there a method that will check if a point intersects a rectangle?

Tags: iphone

So, Apple includes a `CGRectIntersectsRect` method which checks if two rectangles are intersecting each other, but do they have a method that I can use the checks if a CGPoint intersects a  CGRect? Or do I just have to implement that myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one: [`CGRectContainsPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint).

Comment: Well, I have to wait another 12 min or so but I'll be sure to accept.